# How can i save changes in to the database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following code to edit product, edit form is created and connected to the database that working fine but i need help saving the changes into the database.

Product Service

```
namespace PDM.Core.App.Common.Product
{
    public interface IProductService
    {        Task<IList<ProductDTO>> GetProducts();

    }
}
```

//Controller

```
public IProductService ProductService { get; }

     public ProductController(IProductService productService)
    {
        ProductService = productService;
    }

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)

    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ProductList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();

        var Product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);

        if (Product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(Product);
    }
```

Edit Action looks like as follow

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ProductEditModel editModel)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var ProductList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();
        var Product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
        if (Product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Product.Code = editModel.Code;
        ProductService.EditProduct(Product);

        return View(Product);
    }
```

And i have  Edit form view as

```
<form asp-action="Edit" class="form-horizontal">
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@Model.Id" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="Code" value="@Model.Code" class="form-control" />
   <button class="btn btn-success Product-edit-button" role="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

EditProduct Model

```
public class ProductEditModel {
public int Id {get;set;}
public string code{get; set;}
}
```

1. how can i create EditProduct in productservice with parameter?
2. how can i fix to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: What is `ProductService`?  What database access technology are you using and where are you using it?  From the description it sounds like `ProductService.EditProduct()` is failing, but we can't see that code.

Comment: @David i added ProductService Code, how can i add `EditProduct` in there?

Comment: @David added more code to my question, please let me know if that doesnt make sense

Comment: Well, according to your `IProductService` interface there *is no* method called `EditProduct`.  So this should be showing you a compiler error telling you that there's no such method.  I guess the way you'd fix it to save to a database is by creating and implementing that method.  Maybe that's just your next step and you haven't gotten there yet?

Comment: @david i have this  `ProductService.EditProduct(Product);` what is the parameter will be for `  Task<ProductDTO> EditProduct(???);`

Comment: It sounds like the parameter would be a model called `Product`.  But honestly it also sounds like this is a good time for you to start with some tutorials on using a database in ASP.NET MVC.  Likely using something like Entity Framework.  Originally it sounded like you have some code to write to your database and that code wasn't working in some way, but now you're asking how to write that code in the first place.  Tutorials are really the best place to start for that.